# Random 400 "token_invalid" errors with Laravel / jwt-auth and Angular / Satellizer app

Tags: php, angularjs, nginx, jwt, satellizer

I have an Angular app that consumes an API I built in Laravel, and I use jwt-auth for token management and satellizer on the front end to send the token with each request.

My live environment (for both the front end and the API - which will be moved to a different server once the app is finished) at the moment consists of 2 AWS EC2 instances running nginx with a load balancer. Both servers have the same jwt secret key.

However, and at the moment I can't work out any pattern to it, I randomly get 400 "token_invalid" errors returned from my api. It is not one particular api route, nor is it on every load of the app. When I get a 400 error, from my /clients endpoint for example, other requests will have returned 200's. Next time, all will return 200's. The time after that I may get 200 returned for /clients but a 400 error for /users.

Could this be an issue with me using a load balancer? The jwt secret key, as I said, is the same on both servers - as all the code is in GIT.

I am not using the jwt.refresh middleware.

One other thing to mention is that I don't ever get 400 errors returned when running the app locally via Homestead, ony in production.

**EDIT** - it seems as though logging out (which clears both my user object (basic details only) and the token from local storage, clearing my cache, then logging back in most often causes the error - is this helpful?

Below is an example of one of my api calls.

**App.js**

```
.service('ClientsService', function($http, $q, __env) {
    this.index = function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.get(__env.apiUrl + '/clients')
            .then(function successCallback(response) {
                    console.log(response.data);
                    deferred.resolve(response.data);
                },
                function errorCallback(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
})
```

**ClientsController.js**

```
.controller('ClientsController', function(ClientsService, $stateParams, $mdDialog, $mdToast) {
            var vm = this;
            ClientsService.index().then(function(clients) {
                console.log('ClientsCtrl init');
                vm.clients = clients.data;
            });
            // other controller code
})
```

I'm really struggling to debug this, so any help would be much appreciated. If any more info is needed, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/1583

solution: use the same jwt secret in .env file